# Detecting Server Side Rendering in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Nuxt.js app that uses Server Side Rendering. However in one of my pages I need to detect if it's SSR for a toggle of one of the components. What are some possible ways of creating an `isSSR` flag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use just

```
process.server
```

Vue exposes two attributes on process global variable. `server` and `client` and one of them is set true according to rendering side.